# How to rasterize a Graphics3D expression into an Image3D?

Tags: graphics3d, image3d, rasterize

I'd like to make a 3d image from a 3d graphics. Unfortunately `Rasterize@Graphics3D[Sphere[]]` gives a 2d image, is there any function like a Rasterize3D that does this?

Comment: Which method of [Stereoscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy) do you want to use?

Comment: @rhermans I'm confused, why is any stereoscopy necessary to generate an Image3D object?

Comment: My confusion, I thought you wanted a flat 2D image not an `Image3D` object. Something like a color anaglyph (red/blue glases) or a stereogram that you haven't specified. My mistake for trying to think about more than one thing at the time.

Comment: good question , but I think the answer is hold your breath for wolfram to implement rasterize3d. (assuming you need a general solution.. if your graphics3d contains only simple objects there may be ways)

Comment: [toot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40858/how-to-work-with-3d-images-of-stl-format)

Comment: 5 months passed, there is still no solution to this? Unbelievable. I think your question is very useful, it is not getting enough attention.

Comment: But if you want generate image3d from such as `DensityPlot3D`, this can be done by calculating the data on a regular mesh first, and using `Image3D[data]` to generate 3d object

Comment: I have a tool that will do this with `Region` data if you'd like. I can package it up and put it on Github or some such.

Comment: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch29.html section "Shape Representation" discusses a method called "depth peeling" to convert 3D mesh to volumetric data.

Comment: This answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33277/6804 gives an approach that rasterizes individual 2D slices at different heights and stacks them into a 3d image.