# How to convert Image3D object into Graphics3D object and vice versa?

Tags: graphics3d, conversion, image3d

There are some rendering options (for example, `Lighting`) which are associated with the `Graphics3D` objects. I cannot apply these options for an `Image3D` object (for example, `ExampleData[{"TestImage3D", "MRknee"}]`).

Is there any way to convert an `Image3D` object into `Graphics3D` object, apply some lighting options and convert back to `Image3D` object?

Comment: `Graphics` is vector graphics containing geometric primitives. `Image` is simply a raster--a grid of pixels. You cannot, in general, recover geometric figures merely from their representation on a grid.

Comment: This is closely related to  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91998/how-to-rasterize-a-graphics3d-expression-into-an-image3d

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `Show`.  This creates a `Graphics3D` containing a `Raster3D`.

In general, expressions convertible to `Graphics` are converted with `Show`.  This works for images, 3D images, graphs, and possibly other things I've forgotten about.

But I'm not sure `Lighting` is ever used in the rendering of 3D images, regardless of whether they are contained in an `Image3D` or a `Graphics3D` through `Raster3D` ...

As for the reverse conversion, that is not possible for arbitrary `Graphics3D`.  But you can always extract a `Raster3D` and transplant its contents into an `Image3D`.

For 2D images, just use `Image[Graphics[...]]`.

Comment: Note that "`Image[Raster[...]]` converts a `Raster` object to an image" and "`Image3D[Raster3D[...]]` converts a `Raster3D` object to a 3D image" (from the "Details and Options" fields of `Image` and `Image3D` Documentaion pages). As opposed to this, `Image[Graphics[...]]` uses `Rasterize` under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

For Graphics3D -> Image3D:

This answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33277/6804 gives an approach that rasterizes individual 2D slices at different heights and stacks them into a 3d image.

Of course you need to select a resolution, the conversion will not be lossless in general (and I don't know what would happen when the Graphics3D object is a Show@Image3D... maybe you get a resampling, or nothing).