# Turning a simple 3D Image to Graphics3D for 3D printing

Tags: graphics3d, 3d-printing

```
my3dobj = Image3D@Array[   Boole@FreeQ[Plus @@ Mod[PadLeft@IntegerDigits[{##} - 1, 3], 2, 1],      3 | 4] &, {3, 3, 3}^3]
```

Got this from [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/392391). I'd like to 3D print it.

```
Printout3D[Show@my3dobj]
Printout3D[my3dobj]
```

Tried solutions like `Image3D[Raster3D[...]]` and `Show[]` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113836/how-to-convert-image3d-object-into-graphics3d-object-and-vice-versa). Does not really work.

[image]

How can I export this to 3D printer using `Printout3D[ ]` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Printout3D` needs a region not an image. I see a few ways to construct your region of interest. Here each subsequent solution is more roundabout than the last.

Method 1:

```
Printout3D[MengerMesh[3, 3]]
```

Method 2:

```
arr = Array[Boole@FreeQ[Plus @@ Mod[PadLeft@IntegerDigits[{##} - 1, 3], 2, 1], 3 | 4] &, {3, 3, 3}^3];

Printout3D[ArrayMesh[arr]]
```

Method 3:

```
Printout3D[ImageMesh[Image3D[arr]]]
```

All solutions output ‘Successful’ on my machine:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
array = Array[
 Boole@FreeQ[
  Plus @@ Mod[PadLeft@IntegerDigits[{##} - 1, 3], 2, 1], 
  3 | 4
  ] &, {3, 3, 3}^3
 ];
Printout3D@ArrayMesh@array
```