# How to dilate or erode a 3D geometry import with STL format?

Tags: image-processing, import, image3d

I am a freshman to Mathematica. I just wonder if it is possible to dilate or erode directly the 3D geometry in STL format.

I have tried to import a STL file and then used Dilation function. However, the result shows that only a 2D image is dilated.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Shen

Comment: Please see `ref / format / STL` and pick an example to work with or provide one on your own. Then describe the effect on the mesh you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Let's see the reference of the function Dilation. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dilation.html   What I need is shown exactly in the example of 3D image in the site.      However,  when I import a STL file of my own, it seems this is not a 3D image. Therefore, the Dilation function did not work.

Comment: So do you want to convert a mesh to image 3d or to do something with mesh?

Comment: I just want to dilate my 3D geometry imported with STL format. I do not know much about the image format in mathematica. When I see the reference, it says it is possible to use the Dilation[] function to dilate a 3D image. So i'd rather have a try.    Maybe it is possible to dilate an image in image 3D. Thank you for showing me something in detail.     BTW, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40858/how-to-work-with-3d-images-of-stl-format    this tutorial seems not work in my case.

Comment: That might be due to the fact that `Import[]` now imports \*.stl files as `MeshRegion[]` objects, while the functions in the thread you linked to expect `Graphics3D[]`.