# Conversion of STL files to 3D Images

Tags: import, parallelization, image3d, 3d-printing

I am trying to convert some stl files to 3d images in MMA 11.3.  I came across [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40858/how-do-i-convert-imported-stl-files-to-3d-images/125296#125296) that contained some code making use of parallelization to speed up the process, as follows:

```
voxelify[region_?RegionQ, res_?NumericQ] := 

Module[{f, bounds, boxsize, voxsize, data, d2},
  f = RegionDistance[region];
  bounds = RegionBounds[region]; 
  boxsize = -Subtract @@ # & /@ bounds;
  voxsize = Max[boxsize]/res; 
  data = ParallelArray[f[{##}] &, Round[boxsize/voxsize], bounds]; 
  d2 = HeavisideTheta[data - voxsize]; 
  2 - ReplaceAll[WatershedComponents[Image3D[1 - d2]], {0 -> 2}]
  ]
```

Very nice.  Unfortunately it doesnt work, but produces an error message:

[image]

It then proceeds with a very slow sequential evaluation taking several minutes, rather than seconds.

Thinking that perhaps this was due to changes in the functionality of ParallelArray, I reinstalled MMA10.0, then MMA10.3, but they both produced the same error.  I have no idea how the OP got the code to work originally.

Is anyone able to suggest a fix for this code?  Or an alternative approach that is equally efficient?

Comment: Have you seen [`RegionImage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionImage.html)?

Comment: Yes, but I am not clear how that helps....